# Get count of unique values in a column prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

I'm doing a project on visualizing citizenship data in a, and I want to visualize and count the number of unique values in the column "KK", and I can't seem to find out how, I've tried using groupby, and distinct but none seem to work, can anyone help out?

```
model Warga {
  id                 Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  kk                 String
  nik                String             @unique
  namaLengkap        String
  tempatLahir        String
  jenisKelamin       JenisKelamin
  agama              Agama
  noTelp             String
  alamatKK           String
  alamatDomisili     String
  noRumah            Int
  rt                 Int
  statusPerkawinan   StatusPerkawinan
  statusPekerjaan    StatusPekerjaan
  jenisPekerjaan     String?
  pendapatan         Int?
  statusKependudukan StatusKependudukan
  createdAt          DateTime           @default(now())
}
```

above is the schema I'm working with, the project is made with nextjs with typescript

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's an open issue about count by distinct feature, you can find a workaround [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4228)